# IE6/7 bug: there are empty space without any logical reason

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

This is really strange (well, like many IE bugs lol). The page is [here](http://gedrap.com/leatherbound/). Everything is fine with all modern browsers, but there is an empty space between footer and the bottom of the page on IE6 and IE7. Just can't imagine what is the reason. I am using IE7.js hack, but doesn't help here.

The screenshots: [IE6](http://media.crossbrowsertesting.com/users/32114/screenshots/full/z120d01b4fcccbb75512.png) and [IE7](http://media.crossbrowsertesting.com/users/32114/screenshots/full/zb797ee3ddd1ff0e2a11.png).

CSS for footer:

```
#footer {
    background: url("images/footer_bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Special Elite',arial,serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 85px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    min-height: 85px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I tried to look at the page in IE 7 mode in IE 9, but it crashes the browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `float:left` from the footer,

then that makes other browsers "collapse" the top margin of the `#footer`, so if you also add `overflow: hidden` to the `#wrapper` it should make them even..

re:bug : the widths for IE6/7 are triggering hasLayout  and instead of avoiding that, the overflow on the wrapper makes everyone the same

at least I hope ;)